# Why doesn't \newline work inside lstlisting?

Tags: listings, line-breaking

I am new to LaTeX and am using a template provided by a friend:

```
 \subsection{P2P library}
The library is implemented in C-Sharp and provides two basic facilities - maintaining a member list at every instance and the support for receving and multicasting UDP data. 

The public methods it has are 
\begin{lstlisting}
      void setPorts(int recvHere \newline, int sendFrom
```

Why doesn't `,int sendFrom` move to a new line in the PDF output? In fact it just shows up in the PDF output.

Comment: The `listings` is a verbatim environment so that the usual macros are not executed. You can specify a character to escape you to latex and you will need to insert that character around `\newline`.

Comment: so what other option do I have?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As commented by Peter Grill, `lstlisting` is a verbatim environment, meaning that its contents are printed exactly as they appear in the code. As this also includes linebreaks, you could simply add a linebreak in the code.

```
\begin{lstlisting}
      void setPorts(int recvHere 
      , int sendFrom
\end{lstlisting}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can escape to latex using `escapechar=\&`.  Then enclose the LaTeX macros you want executed within a `&` pair:

[image]

For simply inserting a new line, best to probably manually do it as per TorbjørnT's solution. But if you want to imbed more useful macros then specifying an `escapechar` will be needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{% Add other global options here
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  escapechar=\&% char to escape out of listings and back to LaTeX
}


\begin{document}
\subsection{P2P library}
The public methods it has are 
\begin{lstlisting}
      void setPorts(int recvHere &\newline& int sendFrom
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worth noting that simply typing a line break affects the line numbers. Your solution with `&\newline&` performs the line break without incrementing lstlisting's line numbers. Therefore both solutions have their own uses.

Answer (score 3):

another escape way is to define **escapeinside** field.

```
\lstset{escapeinside={\%*}{*)}
```

means that between %* and *) characters you can write latex commmands.

For example,

```
\begin{lstlisting}
  void setPorts(int recvHere,  %*\newline*) int sendFrom)
```

The answer is similar to Peters' but i couldn't add the comment to his answer since i have not enough reputation...)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!