# Can't insert newlines in the code listing

Tags: listings, line-breaking

I am currently trying to insert a batch file programming code in my report. I am using the code listing. I am not able to add new lines to format my code! I have following code example yet:

```
 \begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=ä]
 ä\colorbox{white}{\color{RoyalBlue}\texttt{Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.}}ä
```

The output is like this in a single line which I don't prefer: Microsoft Windows Version 6.2.9200 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

The output I desire should be:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
>
> (c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

I have tried to use inserting newline by using `\\`, `\newline` etc. after first line, nothing helped me.
Any suggestion from you are welcome. Please note that latex's code listing([Supported languages](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings)) doesn't support Batch file programming language syntax.

Comment: Please, take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49021/why-doesnt-newline-work-inside-lstlisting?rq=1

Comment: You cannot have line breaks inside a `\colorbox`

Comment: Close voters: the question here is different from the linked one. The cause here is the box, as daleif observes, rather than anything to do with using a verbatim environment (which is escaped here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely there are better methods, but what about using a `\parbox`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=ä]
 ä\colorbox{yellow}{%
  \parbox{3.9in}{\color{blue}\texttt{Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]\\\\
   (c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.}}}ä
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. I've changed the colors only just to emphasize the result.

Comment: Hello karlkoeller, Is it possible to preserve white spaces in \parbox before a line starts. I am unable to ident the code.

Comment: @pss You'd better ask another question for this, providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` so to reproduce your situation. BTW: you have enough reputation now to upvote answers and questions, when you like them.

Comment: done it here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128582/how-to-preserve-tabs-and-whitespaces-in-parbox-in-latex