# How to preserve tabs and whitespaces in \parbox in latex

Tags: spacing, listings, boxes

I am currently trying to insert a batch file programming code in my report. I am using the code listing. I am not able to preserve white spaces and tabs to format my code! I tried using \hspace but it didn't worked. I have following code example yet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=ä]
     ä\colorbox{white}{%
      \parbox{3.9in}{\color{black}\texttt{Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]\\\\
       (c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.}}}ä
    \end{lstlisting}

    \end{document}
```

The output is like this which I don't prefer:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]

(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

I prefer a tab or white space before the second line starts. The output I prefer is as below:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]

      (c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask why you are putting it into a box, which means you don't get verbatim output?

Comment: I don't know why I am using box, I just wanted to add a source code I started with listing then I needed color for text, so I just mixed up box, listing etc. I am new to latex! :( Do you have better idea. All I want to do is produce the output given above in my question with text in blue color. Also with listing I can label my code so I am confused what to use?

Comment: @pss You should have asked how to get started with the `listings` package...

Comment: listing package doesn't support Batch file code

Comment: @pss Why not? Have a look at page 13 in the listings [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) for the predefined languages. Probably `command.com` is the one you're looking for, and, if you can't find the one that matches your needs, you can always create your custom one following the guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily set the style of a `listings` to blue typewriter text by using `\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue}}`. As `lstlisting` is a verbatim environment, all spaces are preserved.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue}}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]

     (c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: You've beaten me for a second. I was adding the same thing in my answer... Anyway the question is different. +1 anyway.

Comment: @karlkoeller Yeah, you're right. Thought it might be useful anyway, that's why I answered. I could always delete it, if it doesn't fit.

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: In this case how are white spaces and tabs handled? Should I simply type my text with tabs and spaces and it will show up exactly the same? Thanks

Comment: @pss Yes, verbatim means that the text comes out just as typed, including whitespace.

Comment: Thanks, I select this answer because the approach is simple for a noob like me. Thanks to all the persons who answered!

Comment: @TorbjørnT. T. Can I change the font to consolas font type?

Comment: @pss That is quite a different question actually. Yes, you can. If Inconsolata is good enough, add `\usepackage{inconsolata}`. If you need Consolas, the easiest is if you can use either `xelatex` or `lualatex` to compile your document, and replace `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmonofont{Consolas}`. The `fontspec` package, which can only be used with `xelatex` and `lualatex`, allows you to use any TrueType/OpenType font installed in your system.

Comment: I added the package you mentioned but do I need to specify the font type somewhere like in here: \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue}} ?

Comment: @pss No, the `inconsolata` package changes the monospace font to Inconsolata, and `\ttfamily` means that the monospace font is used. If you're interested in a little more about the other option `fontspec`, you can take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37251/586

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10168/discussion-between-pss-and-torbjorn-t)

Answer (score 6):

One easy way is to add an `\hphantom` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=ä]
 ä\colorbox{white}{%
  \parbox{4.3in}{\color{black}\texttt{Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]\\\\
  \hphantom{Micros}(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.}}}ä
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but how can I adjust the amount of white space? Sometimes I need more space and some times less!

Comment: @pss Inside `\hphantom` you can write as many characters as you want. Add or remove characters to achieve what you want (and adjust the width of the `\parbox`). In your case it is even easier since the characters are monospaced.

Comment: \hphantom{Micros} what is this doing? I didn't get it. Thanks

Comment: @pss `\hphantom{}` insert horizontal space with the same size as the content of the braces.